Why $\int_{|x|^2 < r} f(x_1, ..., x_n) \mathrm d x = \int_0^{\sqrt r} \mathrm d s \int_{|x|= s} f(x) \mathrm d S(x)$
I am reading this post the states that for every function $f(x_1, ..., x_n)$ we have
$$\int_{|x|^2 < r} f(x_1, ..., x_n) \mathrm d x = \int_0^{\sqrt r} \mathrm d s \int_{|x|= s} f(x) \mathrm d S(x)\tag{1}$$
with $\mathrm d S(x)$ denoting the surface element of the sphere $\{|x| = r\}$ and $\sigma_{n-1} = \frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$ is the area of the $(n-1)$-sphere.
Could someone please shed some light on why this is true?
Any answer or reference is highly appreciated.

This is polar coordinates in higher dimensions. It’s a corollary of the co-area formula https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula . See the applications section where it mentions explicitly the formula you care about
